# Ionic add empty space between elements

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I was wondering how to add space between two stacked buttons in ionic.

I have two buttons and I want space between them and not between anything else that I might have on the page.

What I want is a placeholder div like component that I can just drop which does this for me.

What I am not looking for is to add gird or to change the CSS.

In short I am looking for a quick and dirty way to add some space.

Comment: Please clarify your question with code and image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ion-row where h is whatever height you want. Make sure you add unit at the end of h (px, vw, vh, rem, etc.)

```
<ion-row style="height: h"></ion-row>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add `&nbsp;` between the two buttons.

Comment: &nbsp with semicolon. `&nbsp;`

Answer (score -1):

```
<label >Subscription Expiry: 2019=04-30 00:00:00<br><br></label>
```

Subscription Type: paid